# What to do the weird function parameters of kdb work?

Tags: kdb

From the execution control chapter, it seems to me that the function parameter has strange implementation like in the code below:

```
zs:{`d`P`L`G`D!(system"d"),v[1 2 3],enlist last v:value x}
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not function parameters. Function parameters will either always be encased in square brackets like so:

```
{[a;b] .... }
```

or they will be implied to be x,y,z if not specified

```
{x+y}
```

What the debug function is doing is running "value" on the supplied function x, which yields useful info as described here in http://code.kx.com/q/ref/metadata/#value

```
Given a function, it returns the list
(bytecode;parameters;locals(context;globals);constants[0];...;constants[n];definition)
```

Then it is extracting the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and last output from that, prepending the current namespace/directory (system"d") and finally creating an output dictionary using d/P/L/G/D as the keys

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. If you look at your link and see the globals has out as `d. Question is why is the variable name which is just d has a backtick before it. The variable d does not have a backtick before it in the function body.  A general question is why is a backtick required during enumeration or when refering to a foreign key. I guess this is a language lawerly question but would appreciate some input.

Comment: It's a symbol representing the variable name, often used for working with variables/functions dynamically. The same reason why you get a list of function names as symbols when you type `key .q`, or why you see a variable a as a symbol if you run `parse"1+a"` (parse creates a parse tree representing how q interprets and executes your code). Q knows to resolve the backtick to refer to the underlying variable you called a. Details here http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/parse_tree